# Pin OS X Terminal to the Desktop Background

Tags: macos, terminal, desktop

I am looking for a tool that can 'stick' the OS X terminal app to the desktop background. I want it to be below the desktop icons, on top or instead of the background image.

I am using the terminal through out the day, from time to time. But I don't really need it for ongoing tasks, only to check something very fast. So having an active corner that shows the desktop would be the ideal guesture to reveal the terminal.

GeekTool has the ability to present the output of a terminal command on a desktop, however, I haven't been able to type something into the terminal overlay, GeekTool is showing. Is there any other tool, that could achieve that?

Comment: I'm using Total Terminal http://totalterminal.binaryage.com . It let's You show Terminal using system-wide Hot Key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stock Script Editor app to save the following script as an application (.app file):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd ~/Desktop"
end tell
```

You can edit the script above to specify the directory you want the new window to use by default.
Once you've created your .app file you can put it on your desktop and conveniently double click it to open a new terminal window.